# Laravel Relationship not working on server

Tags: laravel, server, relationship

My project is working fine on local host, but on the server, getting error only on lesson page.

Subject Model is

```
    class Subjects extends Model
  {
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Lea\Category');
    }
    public function lesson()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Lea\Lessons');
    }
    public function chapter()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Lea\Chapters');
    }
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Lea\User', 'subject_user', 'subject_id', 'user_id');
    }
  }
```

And Lesson Model is

```
    class Lessons extends Model
{
    public function chapter()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Lea\Chapters');
    }
    public function subject()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Lea\Subjects', 'subject_id');
    }
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Lea\Category');
    }

}
```

My controller lessons has method index like below.

```
public function index()
    {

        $lessons = lessons::orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.lessons.index')->withLessons($lessons);
    }
```

The way i am calling subject name is show below. first subject is relationship subject and 2nd subject is the field name where subject name saved in db. using foreach to get data like:

```
@foreach ($lessons as $lesson)
{{$lesson->subject->subject}}
@endforeach
```

subjects table schema is

```
id
subject
admin_id
users_id
category_id
created_at
updated_at
```

lessons table schema is

```
id
title
slug
category_id
subject_id
chapter_id
users_id
content
image
```

Comment: What are your field names in your tables?  Is it possible that you have followed the same logic as subject_id and subject_user and have actually named the field "subject_name"?  The issue appears to be in your subject table

Comment: if field name is problem then it should give me some json output putting this code {{$lesson->subject}} but i am getting null on server but json on localhost

Comment: are you persisting the $lesson object to your view through your controller?

Comment: there are so many levels this error could be occurring so you would have to provide all of your code if we are going to be able to find the problem

Comment: i edited my question with controller and view

Comment: Providing the error you are receiving would help a lot.

Comment: error is Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: getting null after putting {{$lesson->subject}}

Answer (score 0):

That's more like it ;)

Just edit how you are passing the object to the following:

```
...
return view('admin.lessons.index')->with(compact('lessons'));
```

What this is doing:

compact() essentially takes the object/variable by it's name ($lessons) and passes it to the view with the same name.

An alternative way is to write it as:

```
...   
return view('admin.lessons.index')->with('lessons', $lessons);
```

Cheers!

Comment: Returning is not issue, i am getting non relationship values with my method. just relationship value for lesson and subject is not being display, while relationship with category is also working

Comment: why is your field name subject_id?  Wouldn't it be simpler just keep it as id?  If you say category is working then it may be an issue with the primary key you are defining for the subject table.

Comment: its foreign key in lesson table.

Comment: Post your lessons and subjects schemas please

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the error in your server but not your local machine is that your server database is empty (or at least has fewer records).

`{{$lesson->subject->subject}}`

The lesson has no subject, so it's null. And your tryting to get a proprty `subject` of a null.

If you're using Laravel 5.5, you can wrap the subject in `optional()` method.

`{{optional($lesson->subject)->subject}}`

< Laravel 5.5
`{{$lesson->subject ? $lesson->subject->subject : ''}}`